# I have made a category and want to make sub category, how can I add dynamically?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I made a form in which I have titlte, image, pdf, content and category and all are working fine, but I want to add submenu in my form and also want to make this dynamic so can show all sub-menu on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to intruduce a key `parent_id` with categories table.

And in category model do create the relation like this.

```
class Category extends Model
{


    public $fillable = ['title','parent_id'];


    /**
     * Get the index name for the model.
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function childs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id','id') ;
    }
}
```

Here you can find the complete example..https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-category-treeview-hierarchical-structure-example-with-demoexample.html

Hopefully this could help you.

Comment: thanks, I tried but I have a form in which first I am adding the subcategory for specific category ex people->1 bad people,2 good people. so I can post the data for submenu under menu from my admin

Comment: Please include piece of code with your question for the better visibility of query.

Comment: You can just use the `onChange` event for the parent catgory and call with ajax request to get the child categories data and fill that. Else you can also filter the child categories based on the parent selection..if you have already got the child in single glance.

Comment: Here is the example for the onchange event. http://jsfiddle.net/b9tMU/13/

Comment: You don't need to create another table...only one table would be enough for this category tree.

Comment: If you would like to add more category inside another... it's as easy as simple... did you checked the example here.. http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/category-tree-view

Comment: Here is the tutorial to follow. https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-category-treeview-hierarchical-structure-example-with-demoexample.html

Comment: Just add your extra fields whatever required.

Comment: thanks , I am trying to do and once will complete, will let you know, so it's 11:06 am here, after 15 min or less 11:21

Comment: I am trying but new problem is that, I have already made a category model and in which, I have data and for this I made template, so any another way to make

Comment: Sorry! which template?

Comment: I have  category or submenu and make all dynamic in my website and home, contact, prodiuct, about and for each I want different designed so made template so can get different designed when post the new things in different menu

Comment: I know it's hard to understand and sorry I am new in this so not getting the exact way to do, if you in fb, so can send all code

Comment: No need to wipe all data... just add a field `parent_id` with your existing table... migrate data from subcategories -> categories table and follow the tutorial for rest of the logic. For the business logic, you might have better understanding.

Comment: Here you can get help on a particular problem only :)

Comment: I know but still bad,